# Oracle recursive query (comparing timestamps within grouped data)

Tags: oracle, recursion, subquery

I have data where several people can belong to the same account ID, with the original member being a primary. I am trying to write a query that for each account ID that has one or more members, returns any non-primare account with a timestamp greater than the primary.

So using sample data:

```
ID  account ID  Timestamp   Primary
1   111        4/26/2011 0:00   1
2   112        4/26/2011 0:00   1
3   112        4/27/2011 0:00   0
4   113        4/26/2011 0:00   1
5   113        4/29/2011 0:00   0
6   113        4/28/2011 0:00   0
7   114        4/26/2011 0:00   1
8   114        4/26/2011 0:00   0
```

I would like to return the following

```
ID  account ID  Timestamp   Primary
3   112         4/27/2011 0:00  0
5   113         4/29/2011 0:00  0
6   113         4/28/2011 0:00  0
```

So the flow is as follows:

1. Find all account IDs with > 1 records
2. For each of these account ids, return all non-primary records (i.e. primary = 0) where the timestamp is greater than for the primary records for that account ID.

In a short I'm trying to find all members who where added to the account at a later date.

I've been looking at subqueries and hierarchical queries but could definitely use some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, account_ID, "Timestamp", "Primary" ) AS
SELECT 1, 111, TIMESTAMP '2011-04-26 00:00:00', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 112, TIMESTAMP '2011-04-26 00:00:00', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 112, TIMESTAMP '2011-04-27 00:00:00', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 113, TIMESTAMP '2011-04-26 00:00:00', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 113, TIMESTAMP '2011-04-29 00:00:00', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 113, TIMESTAMP '2011-04-28 00:00:00', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 114, TIMESTAMP '2011-04-26 00:00:00', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 114, TIMESTAMP '2011-04-26 00:00:00', 0 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LAG( CASE "Primary" WHEN 1 THEN 1 END ) IGNORE NULLS
           OVER ( PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY "Timestamp", "Primary" )
           AS has_prev_primary
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  has_prev_primary = 1;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID ACCOUNT_ID Timestamp                       Primary HAS_PREV_PRIMARY
---------- ---------- ----------------------------- --------- ----------------
         3        112 2011-04-27 00:00:00.000000000         0                1 
         6        113 2011-04-28 00:00:00.000000000         0                1 
         5        113 2011-04-29 00:00:00.000000000         0                1
```

Comment: Thank you!! This was exactly what I was looking for